# How can I actively see the cornerRadius of a button in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I've set the `layer.cornerRadius` of a button in Xcode to be 25 to make rounded buttons, but I can't see this property updated in Storyboard directly.

Anyone has any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You should write this line.

```
layer.maskToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I made a superclass called `RButton` that is `@IBDesignable` and has a property called `cornerRadius` with the following setters and getters:

```

```
@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
}
```

```